# DataTable Rows with jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I basically want to use Datatables plugin with a custom addition. I'd like to build an Accordion into the table. So when a Table's TD item is clicked a new div appears below it which is whithin the table.

If the person clicks on it again, the div disappears. This is the basic idea I'd like to create.

Is there any plugin or jQuery method to do this easily?

Comment: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html